# How to bulk-delete files in WINDOWS using cmd that don't contain a string in the filename at 2 levels below current directory

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I have on Windows a folder structure like:

```
\---Root 
    \---L1
        \---L2
            \---L3
                +---2022_09_28
                |   +---F1
                |   |       DELETE_D1F1_1.csv
                |   |       DELETE_D1F1_2.csv
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_1.csv
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_2.csv
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_3.csv
                |   |       
                |   \---F2
                |           ab_F2_1.csv
                |           yid_F2_2.csv
                |           
                +---2022_09_29
                |   +---F1
                |   |       DELETE_D1F1_1.csv
                |   |       DELETE_D1F1_2.csv
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_1.csv
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_2.csv
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_3.csv
                |   |       
                |   \---F2
                |           amd_F2_2.csv
                |           fgd_F2_1.csv
```

Please note that the tree structure replicates `\F1` and `\F2`
folders for each calendar date and I've shown just 2 dates here for illustration.

The ask is as follows:

1. Loop on all the folders named - `\F1`
2. Delete the files that are not starting with `DONT_DELETE` in the `\F1` folder

Expected result is **Only** the files starting with `DELETE` would be deleted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure this is DOS?

Comment: Please state your problem in terms of Windows. As it is, your question is hard to understand.

Comment: @jarnosz - Apologies - i meant windows!

Comment: @harrymc  - I've tried to edit and restate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of painfully crafting a batch command, I suggest using an
instant-search utility such as
[Everything of voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/),
which I regard as one of my most useful tools.

After it indexes your disk, you could search your files with this expression:
`files: "\path\root" \F1 !DONT_DELETE*`

Verify the displayed list, and if correct press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then
<kbd>Del</kbd> to delete.

Comment: Would this work even if there are folders names F1 at other levels? (e.g. L2, L3 etc.) I don't want the files under those folders to be affected.

Comment: Truth is - I'm not sure. Try and see if their files are in the list.

Comment: 1) Are the files you need to delete always in the last folder in the directory tree? 2) Does the name always start with a unique string for the files to be deleted?

Comment: Same as item **1)** above but just describing the doubt in another way: Are the files you need to delete always in the last folder of each sub-level of the directory tree?

Comment: @ lo-ol - 1) Yes- to answer your question differently- the files are always under the folder named  .../yyyy-dd-mm/F1/. And there are no other sub-folders under  .../yyyy-dd-mm/F1/.  2) Yes - the name of the files to be deleted always start with a unique string.

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off

2>nul cd /d "z:\root" || exit /b

for /f usebackq^ delims^= %%i in (`
     where /r . *.csv ^| findstr /r .[0-9]\\\F1\\\DELETE.*.csv
    `)do echo\del /q /a: "%%~i"
```

---

- Or...

```bath
@echo off

2>nul cd /d "z:\root" || exit /b

for /f usebackq^ delims^= %%i in (`
     where /r . DELETE*_*.csv^|findstr /e .*[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]\\F1\\.*\.csv
    `)do echo\ del /q /a: "%%~i"
```

---

You can test it and if it looks good remove the `echo\`  to effectively remove your files.

---

For loop command results:

```bath
del /q /a: "z:\root\L1\L2\L3\2022_09_28\F1\DELETE_D1F1_1.csv"
del /q /a: "z:\root\L1\L2\L3\2022_09_28\F1\DELETE_D1F1_2.csv"
del /q /a: "z:\root\L1\L2\L3\2022_09_29\F1\DELETE_D1F1_1.csv"
del /q /a: "z:\root\L1\L2\L3\2022_09_29\F1\DELETE_D1F1_2.csv"
del /q /a: "z:\root\L1\L2\L3\2022_09_30\F1\DELETE_D1F1_1.csv"
del /q /a: "z:\root\L1\L2\L3\2022_09_30\F1\DELETE_D1F1_2.csv"
```

---

You will have in Windows a folder structure like:

```bath
\---Root
    \---L1
        \---L2
            \---L3
                +---2022_09_28
                |   +---F1
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_1.csv
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_2.csv
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_3.csv
                |   |       
                |   \---F2
                |           ab_F2_1.csv
                |           yid_F2_2.csv
                |           
                +---2022_09_29
                |   +---F1
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_1.csv
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_2.csv
                |   |       DONT_DELETE_D1F1_3.csv
                |   |       
                |   \---F2
                |           amd_F2_2.csv
                |           fgd_F2_1.csv
```

Comment: Thanks a ton lo-ol; the script works fine. However, I just have one observation - I want to identify the files to be deleted using the 2 conditions:  1) They should be under the folder F1, 2).  They should satisfy NEGATIVE condition - they SHOULD NOT be STARTing with "DONT_DELETE" .  It appears that instead of the NEGATIVE condition, you have used a POSITIVE condition - files SHOULD be STARTing with "DELETE"..

Comment: Thanks a ton again @ lo-ol ; did some iterations and found that the code below works perfectly for me:                                                                                                          
 @echo off

2>nul cd /d "C:\L1" || exit /b

for /f usebackq^ delims^= %%i in (`
     where /r . *.csv ^| findstr /r .[0-9]\\\F1\\.*\.csv ^| findstr -V "DONT_DELETE"
    `)do echo\del /q /a: "%%~i"
 
pause